# Locate the poles of $ \ f(z)=\frac{z}{1-ae^{-iz}}, \ a>1 \ \ is \ a \ real \ constant. \ $

Tags: complex-analysis

Locate the poles of $  \ f(z)=\frac{z}{1-ae^{-iz}}, \ a>1 \ \ is \ a \ real \ constant. \ $

Then show that $ \int_{C} f(z) dz=0 $ , where $ C $ is the closed contour in the upper half plane.

**Answer:**

f(z) has poles when  $ 1-ae^{-iz}=0 $.

Then , $ e^{iz}=a >1 $ ,

or, $ \ \cos (z)+i \sin(z)=a+0 \cdot i $

or, $ \cos (z)=a \ \ and \ \ \sin z=0 $

Now, $ \sin z=0=\sin (n \pi) , \ \ or \ \ z=n \pi=0, \pi, 2 \pi,.......... $

But $ at \ \ z=0 , \ cos (0)=a>1 $ , which is impossible since $ \cos(0)=1$.

Similarly $ z=\pi , 2 \pi ,... $ does not satisfy the equation

$ \cos z=a $.

**So no pole on real axis.**

**So the function has no plane in the upper half plane**.

Thus $ \int_{C} \frac{z}{1-ae^{-iz}}dz =0$

**Am I right ? Any help ?**

Answer (score 1):

If you write $z=x+iy$ then you have

$e^{iz}=e^{i(x+iy)}=e^{-y+ix}=e^{-y}e^{ix}$

The imaginary part need to be 0, so $x=2n\pi\,\, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Using that we have $e^{-y}=a$ then $y=\log\left( \frac{1}{a}\right)$ and your set of poles is

$A=\left\{ x+iy\in \mathbb{C}| \,\, y=\log\left( \frac{1}{a}\right),x=2n\pi\,\, n\in\mathbb{Z} \right\}$

And if you see, all the poles are in the lower half plane so you have that your integral is equal to cero because of the Residue Theorem.